SPARK GLUE; EMRFS vs HDFS committers for 100.000+ partitions
I have data that i heavily partition. when running historical loads for several years, it can go up to 100.000+ partitions.
the problem being i load them in S3 in dynamic overwrite mode.
The Glue EMFRS Optimized write is enabled. emrfs s3-optimized enabled by default for glue 4.0 which i use.
but it takes forever to load the data into S3.
The spark job does the transformations fairly quickly.
in itself some joins, aggregates,simple transforms.
The only pain point in the treatment itself being a repartition(part_cols) before writing to have only 1 file per partition.
but really if all i mentionned above takes 20-30 minutes in a 10-15workers cluster.
The writing to S3 takes forever.(1hour to 4 hours if really several years of historic). **and meanwhile the workers are useless with CPU usage approx 0% **
do you have any hint on how to save DPU costs?
i know in HDFS such writes would be O(1) complexity but in S3:

it has to List all object and keys in bucket
ensure the file doesn't exit,
delete it otherwise,
put the file

and as i said, workers being idle meanwhile incuring costs.
is there as of today a solution of such a problem ?
PS: I also tried some custom committers Magic and Partition:optimized
but perf is similar to EMFRS S3-optimized; which is really slow for that much partitions
Thanks for your help

do you use "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic"? Can you check spark UI if anything is running on executors? It can happen that main time is taken by rename operation which is done only on driver.

yes! I do a dynamic partition overwrite!
nothing happens in executors.
Dataframe query ends with a "Execute InsertHadoopFsRelationCommand"  way after the last job has run and ended in the executors.
So i also think that main time is effectively taken by renaming from driver. However i enabled elastic auto-scaling and it doesn't remove any executor at the end while only the driver is busy.

From my experience,
"spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic"
in case of a lot of partitions breaks performance even for emrfs s3-optimized committer.
In my project we solved such cases, writing to tmp path without ("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic")
Then use our custom written code which moves and replaces partitions in target directory using s3 client (java, python boto3)
